# Eliminar archivos por extencion en laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de eliminar todos lo archivos de una carpeta que tengan la extensión .jpg es posible usando Storage::delete('file.jpg');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial de Laravel sí.

En inglés: [Deleting files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#deleting-files)

En español (esta parte no está aún traducida): [Borrado de archivos](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#deleting-files)

**De la documentación original:**

> **Deleting Files**
>
> The delete method accepts a single filename or an array of files to
>   remove from the disk:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
>
> Storage::delete('file.jpg');
>
> Storage::delete(['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg']);
> ```
>
> If necessary, you may specify the disk that the file should be deleted
>   from:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
>
> Storage::disk('s3')->delete('folder_path/file_name.jpg');
> ```

Pero para borrar TODOS los archivos con un sufijo determinado hay que hacer lo siguiente:
<sub>* Gracias al [comentario de Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118846/eliminar-archivos-por-extencion-en-laravel-5-5#comment222364_119596)</sub>

```
File::delete(File::glob('path/*.jpg'));
```

Comment: Por lo que veo, la solucion parece ser la siguiente: `File::delete(File::glob('path/*.jpg'));`. Como no entiendo de laravel no estoy seguro, si te parece que es correcto, añadelo a tu respuesta :)

Comment: Gracias Pikon. Lo he verificado y funciona. Esta me la guardo :-D

Comment: Vale aclarar que `File::glob()` es simplemente un wrapper a la función [**glob()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) de PHP (y obviamente acepta los mismos parámetros).

Comment: Tomo nota de los comentarios/correcciones, formato y de asignar el mérito. ¡Uf! me queda mucho que aprender :-D